# Hibernate: Duplicate entries in reference table with unique primary key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two tables Employee and Project

```
Table Employee
emp_id(PK- assigned)  |   emp_name   |   prj_id(FK prj_id of Project table)

Table Project
prj_id(PK- auto generated)   |    prj_name
```

I am using many to one relationship between Employee and Project

PROBLEM: When I run the below code:

```
Project pro = new Project();
emp.setProject(pro);
saveDetails(emp);

public void saveEmployeeDetails( final Employee emp) 
{
    try
    {
        this.hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate( emp);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        logger.info( "Unable to save details", exception );
    }
}
```

It is updating Table Employee and Project but where in Project it is creating new entry for the same proj_name  which is already present. It is updating Table Employee's data and.

Since there is auto generated primary key for Employee and also i am creating new object for Project every time it is saving the new object. How to avoid duplicate  entry ,I am very new to hibernate .I have very less knowledge on it.

find the hbm files

```
<class name="Employee" 
    table="employee">

    <comment>store details of a project</comment>

    <id name="employeeId" type="string">
        <column length="45" name="emp_id" />

        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one cascade="save-update"
        class="Project" fetch="select" lazy="false"
        name="project">

        <column name="prj_id" not-null="true" />

    </many-to-one>
```

```
<class name="Project" 
    table="project">

    <id name="projectId" type="int">
        <column name="prj_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

            <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="projectName"
        type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="prj_name" />
    </property>

     </class>
```

Comment: it is possible to use session or hibernatetemplate....for getting project name or project id or project object correct if am wrong i am just one day exp in hibernat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Project pro = new Project();
pro.setPrj_Id(existingId);
emp.setProject(pro);
```

Comment: for getting existing id i need to make a db call. Is there any other way or option to specify hibernate to do it automatically.

Comment: add it to employee hbm file <many-to-one name="project" column="prj_id" foreign-key="prj_id" fetch="select" lazy="proxy" not-found="ignore" update="false" insert="false"></many-to-one>

Comment: This is updating the project table and not entering duplicate value but prj_id in employee table is null

Comment: need to declare assigned project details for an employee so you need to make db call for projects,i am expecting you when try to add employee details ,u should have project details

Answer (score 0):

`SaveOrUpdate` will create new entity when there is no `@ID` assigned to object you are passing as argument. It will perform merge operation, if there is `@ID`. In your case that is `ProjectID` property.

Comment: you mean annotation to the projectId property in the Project.java

Comment: U are not using annotations but mapping file whitch is fine. I personally prefer annotations. Any way, you have to either pull existing project from DB, OR create UPDATE query that will fullfil your specific requirements.